# Scroll and read every data - python selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, dom, scroll

i am in a project to scroll and get the every posts that everyone posted. the problem is my code not reading every posts (just 2 or 3 and skipping to next). below is my code and i like to have my code in a way that it reads every posts. i also tried changing sleep() duration and pixel count while scrolling and scroll to view options , but no improvement

```
# scrolling and grabbing data  
            for i in range(1000):
                
                element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "mnk10 copy-txt")]')
                # driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight / 2",element)
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)",element)
                # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, -300)",element)
                # driver.execute_script("return, document.body.scrollHeight/4",element)
                data1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "mnk10 copy-txt")]').get_attribute('dat-plin-txt')
                
                print(data1)
                time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to scroll by a certain amount of one post instead of "scrollIntoView(true)" using the following script part:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 500)", element)
```

you might or might not have to change the "500" part